# Connected Product of Topological Spaces Implies Connectedness of Each Space?

Tags: general-topology

This is a slightly subtle problem, for every proof I have seen concerning "product" and "connectedness" is always goes like "Show the product of connected spaces is connected." But I was considering the reverse, that is : If $\prod_{\alpha\in I}X_{\alpha}$ is a connected nonempty arbitrary product of topological spaces, is it true that for each $\alpha\in I$, where $I$ is any index set, $X_{\alpha}$ is connected? To prove that, I am lost for ideas. Do I need to show that the only close-open subsets of $\prod_{\alpha\in I}X_{\alpha}$ are $\prod_{\alpha\in I}X_{\alpha}$ and $\emptyset$? Or to show that no continuous and onto function from $\prod_{\alpha\in I}X_{\alpha}$ to $\lbrace0,1\rbrace$ with discrete topology can exist?

Comment: It is false. $X_a$ might fail to be connected if $X_{a_0} = \emptyset$ for some $a_0 \in I$. For example, $\emptyset \times (\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}) = \emptyset$ is connected, while $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ isn't. If all $X_a$ are all nonempty, then it is true (use the fact that continuous image of connected set is connected).

Comment: So if I define projection mapping $\pi_{\alpha}:\prod_{\alpha\in I}\to X_{\alpha}$ for each $\alpha\in I$, because $X_{\alpha}\neq\emptyset$ for each $\alpha$, and we know that projection mapping is surjective and continuous, then from the fact that $\prod_{\alpha\in I}$ is connected, $X_{\alpha}$ is connected for each $\alpha$. Is it true?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: @Mason This is a matter of convention. If you define connected so that empty spaces are not connected then the claim is true.